# Django: Efficiently updating many to many relation

Tags: django, performance

Let's say we have a Django `User` with a lot of `Group`s. We want to update the groups with a new list of groups.

A simple but not performant solution could be:

```
def update_users_groups(new_groups: List[Group]):
     user.groups.set(new_groups)
```

A little bit more performant solution is something similar to:

```
def update_users_groups(new_groups: List[Group]):
     new_groups = set([x.id for x in new_groups])
     old_groups = set([x.id for x in user.groups.all()])
     groups_to_add = new_groups - old_groups
     if groups_to_add:
         user.groups.add(*groups_to_add)
     groups_to_remove = old_groups - new_groups
     if groups_to_remove:
         user.groups.remove(*groups_to_remove)
```

I could not find any hints in the documentation for a built-in method. Is there some best practice or any way I could improve my example from above? Maybe even s.o. has an idea for a more performant solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the first example you can just use `.set()`. No need to clear it before. It's the most readable one and I will go with that solution

Comment: Ah true, I edit my post, thanks!

Still it is not more performant, right?

Comment: Do you have performance issue with this approach? I never had one. As someone said:  `premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.`

Comment: @BartoszStasiak not in this particular case of users and groups, but with other many-to-many relations.